# Answered: children's onChange was not Updating the Parent : Ant Design `Select` and `Table` inside `Tab` was not changing according to `pageSize`

Tags: javascript, react-native, next.js, react-hooks, antd

The question is: How can I print "page + new page: 10 + 10" in the console?

I have a part of code like below for (somewhat long Operate page)

```
const defaultPageSize = 5;//operateConstants.OP_DEFAULT_ITEM_PAGESIZE;
const MemberManagement: React.FC = () => {
  //table page size dropdown
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(defaultPageSize);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("pageSize changed to " + pageSize);
  }, [pageSize]);

  const derivedPageSize = pageSize * 2;
  console.log("derivedPageSize: " + derivedPageSize);

  const handlePageSizeChange = (newPageSize: number) => {
    setPageSize(newPageSize);
    console.log("page + new page: " + pageSize + " + " + newPageSize);
    message.info("page + new page: " + pageSize + " + " + newPageSize);
    let newPageSize2 = returnV();
    console.log("Using function returnV : " + newPageSize2);
    setPageSize(newPageSize2);
  };

  function returnV(){ return derivedPageSize;}
}
export default MemberManagement;
```

The message prints "page + new page: 5 + 10" when I need it to print "page + new page: 10 + 10".

So, I tried to console log using useEffect, and it printed
"pageSize changed to 10" and "derivedPageSize: 20"
when I changed the pageSize value to 10.

I thought this was easy; if I make a function call returnV returning derivedPageSize, it should print the changed value. But it printed "Using function returnV : 10" when it's supposed to be 20, values not updated like handlePageSizeChange
[(console_Log_For_PageSize_Change)][(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQJ1p.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3hNr.png)
. I don't know how to print "page+newpage:10 + 10" inside the handlePageSizeChange.

However, in my other page(CS page), setPageSize works fine like this, which is confusing.

```
const defaultPageSize = csConstants.CS_DEFAULT_PAGESIZE;
export default function Tcs() {
  //table page size dropdown
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(defaultPageSize);
  const handlePageSizeChange = (newPageSize: number) => {
    setPageSize(newPageSize);
  };
};
```

I have asked chat-gpt and Google, useCallback from React, tried setting the key=pageSize for the Table element to re-render when pageSize gets updated, tried making a function like returnV. I think [When useState update then map loop is not working in array inside of object in useState. React js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68333856/when-usestate-update-then-map-loop-is-not-working-in-array-inside-of-object-in-u) had a similar question, but with array type.

I think the problem has to do with the timing of rendering or compiling with the const setPageSize, along with the code size but I have no clue where the error is. So, if you know the reason I cannot call handlePageSizeChange and have setPageSize resetting my pageSize like my other page(CS), please explain for me.

**(1)edited to show Reproducible Code____________________below**

The another question is: I think it has to do with elements rendered within another element, but in my eyes rn, **Operate** and **CS** page's *handlePageSizeChange* looks pretty much the same, but one works while other one doesn't. So why is that?

Reproducible Code for (Needs fixing :: Operate page), (functioning :: CS page) below:

**(Needs fixing :: Operate page)**

```
'use client';

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Row, Col, Select, message, Tabs, Table } from 'antd';
import type { ColumnsType } from 'antd/es/table';
import type { TableRowSelection } from 'antd/es/table/interface';
import * as styles from '@/constants/styles';

//range-picker

// Profile Information : Item
interface DataProfileType {
  ID: number | string;
  ITEM_NAME: string;
  DATE_OF_ACQUISITION: Date | string;
}

const ProfileInformationData: DataProfileType[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  ProfileInformationData.push({
    ID: i >= 9 ? 2023 + `${i + 1}` : 2023 + `0${i + 1}`,
    ITEM_NAME: 'name',
    DATE_OF_ACQUISITION:('YYYY-MM-DD-HH-mm-ss'),
  });
}

const ProfileInformation: ColumnsType<DataProfileType> = [
  { title: 'ID', dataIndex: 'ID', align: 'center' },
  { title: 'item', dataIndex: 'ITEM_NAME', align: 'center' },
  { title: 'date', dataIndex: 'DATE_OF_ACQUISITION', align: 'center' },

];

//item data-table pageSize dropdown
const ALIST = {
  "0": "pageSizeSelection",
  "5": "count by 5",
  "10": "count by 10",
  "20": "count by 20"
}
const dropdownList: { [key: string]: string } = ALIST;
const itemPageProps = Object.keys(ALIST).map((key) => ({
  value: Number(key),
  label: dropdownList[key],
  disabled: Number(key) === 0,
}));
const defaultPageSize = 5;

const Operate: React.FC = () => {
  const [pageSize = defaultPageSize, setPageSize] = useState<number>();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("pageSize " + pageSize);
  }, [pageSize]);

  const handlePageSizeChange = (newPageSize: number) => {
    setPageSize(newPageSize);
    console.log("page + new page: " + pageSize + " + " + newPageSize);
    message.info("page + new page: " + pageSize + " + " + newPageSize);
  };

  const rowSelection: TableRowSelection<DataProfileType> = {
    onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
      console.log(`selectedRowKeys: ${selectedRowKeys}`, 'selectedRows: ', selectedRows);
    },
  };
  // tab 1
  const InitialSetting = () => {
    return (
      <>
      <Row>
          <Select //
            key={pageSize}
            size="middle"
            value={pageSize}
            options={itemPageProps}
            defaultValue={defaultPageSize}
            onChange={handlePageSizeChange}
            className="w-[150px]"
          />
          </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col span={24}>
            <Table
              rowKey={(record) => record.ID}
              columns={ProfileInformation}
              dataSource={ProfileInformationData}
              rowSelection={rowSelection}
              bordered
              size="middle"
              pagination={{
                showSizeChanger: false,
                pageSize: pageSize,
                position: ['bottomCenter'],
              }}
              className={styles.darkline_t}
            />

          </Col>
        </Row>
      </>
    );
  };

  //tab 2
  const NFTInformation = () => {
    return <>tab 2</>;
  };

  const initialItems = [
    { label: 'defaultTab', key: '1', children: InitialSetting() },
    { label: 'Tab2', key: '2', children: NFTInformation() },
  ];

  const [items, setItems] = useState(initialItems);

  return (
    <>
          <Row gutter={12}>
        <Col span={24}>
          <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" type="card" size={'middle'} items={items} />
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  );

};

export default Operate;
```

**(functioning :: CS page)**

```
'use client';

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Space, Select } from 'antd';
import { Col, Row, Table, message } from 'antd';
import type { TableProps} from 'antd';
import type { ColumnsType, SorterResult } from 'antd/es/table/interface';

//data-table orderBy dropdown
const CS_1 = {
  "0": "--",
  "col_key1d": "sort1",
  "col_key5d": "sort1",
  "col_key5a": "sort1",
  "col_key6d": "sort1",
  "col_key6a": "sort1",
};
const CS_2 = {
  "0": "pageSize",
  "5": "5pageSize",
  "10": "10pageSize",
  "20": "20pageSize"
};
const CS_DATA_DROPDOWN1: { [key: string]: string } = CS_1;
const menuProps1 = Object.keys(CS_DATA_DROPDOWN1).map((key) => ({
  value: key,
  label: CS_DATA_DROPDOWN1[key],
  disabled: key === "0",
}));

const CS_DATA_DROPDOWN2: { [key: string]: string } = CS_2;
//data-table pageSize dropdown
const menuProps2 = Object.keys(CS_DATA_DROPDOWN2).map((key) => ({
  value: Number(key),
  label: CS_DATA_DROPDOWN2[key],
  disabled: Number(key) === 0,
}));

//----------------------------------------------------------Default Values
const defaultPageSize = 5;
const defaultOrderBy = "col_key1d";
//----------------------------------------------------------end Default Values
//main
export default function CS() {

  //table order dropdown
  const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = useState(defaultOrderBy);
  const handleOrderByChange = (newOrderBy: string) => {
    setOrderBy(newOrderBy);
    const order = newOrderBy.endsWith("d") ? "descend" : "ascend";
    const col = newOrderBy.substring(0, newOrderBy.length - 1);
    const columnKey = col as keyof DataType;
    setSortedInfo({ columnKey, order });
  };

  //table page size dropdown
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(defaultPageSize);
  const handlePageSizeChange = (newPageSize: number) => {
    console.log("page + new page: " + pageSize + " + " + newPageSize);
    message.info("page + new page: " + pageSize + " + " + newPageSize);
    setPageSize(newPageSize);
  };
  //----------------------------------------------------------end dropdown

  //----------------------------------------------------------data-table
  const [sortedInfo, setSortedInfo] = useState<SorterResult<DataType>>({
    columnKey: defaultOrderBy.substring(0, defaultOrderBy.length - 1),
    order: defaultOrderBy.endsWith("d") ? "descend" : "ascend"
  });

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  interface DataType {
    key: React.Key;
    col_key1: string,
     col_key5: string; col_key6:string;
  }
  const data: DataType[] = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    data.push({
      key: i,
      col_key1: `${i} a-`,
      col_key5: `2023-03-14-01-01-01`,
      col_key6: `2023-03-15-01-01-02`,
    });
  }

  const handleChange: TableProps<DataType>['onChange'] = (pagination, filters, sorter) => {
    console.log('Various parameters', pagination, filters, sorter);
    setSortedInfo(sorter as SorterResult<DataType>);
  };
  const columns: ColumnsType<DataType> = [
    {
      title: 'a1',
      dataIndex: 'col_key1',
      key: 'col_key1',
      align: 'center',
      width: 120,
      sortOrder: sortedInfo.columnKey === 'col_key1' ? sortedInfo.order : null,
    },
    {
      title: 'd',
      dataIndex: 'col_key5',
      key: 'col_key5',
      align: 'center',
      
      sortOrder: sortedInfo.columnKey === 'col_key5' ? sortedInfo.order : null,
    },
    {
      title: <div className="text-center">e</div>,
      dataIndex: 'col_key6',
      key: 'col_key6',
      align: 'center',
      sorter: (a, b) => a.col_key6.length - b.col_key6.length,
      sortOrder: sortedInfo.columnKey === 'col_key6' ? sortedInfo.order : null,
    },
  ];

  //---------------------------------------------------------- end data-table

  //main
  return (
    <>
      <Row justify={'space-between'} align={'middle'} className="mt-4">
        <Col xs={24} md={12} className="flex flex-wrap justify-end">
          <Space size={'middle'} className="flex flex-wrap">
            <Select
              value={orderBy}
              defaultValue={defaultOrderBy}
              size="middle"
              options={menuProps1}
              onChange={handleOrderByChange}
              className="w-[150px]"
            />
            <Select
              size="middle"
              value={pageSize}
              options={menuProps2}
              defaultValue={defaultPageSize}
              onChange={handlePageSizeChange}
              className="w-[150px]"
            />
          </Space>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col span={24}>
          <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} loading={loading} onChange={handleChange}
            pagination={{
              position: ["bottomCenter"], pageSize: pageSize, onShowSizeChange: handlePageSizeChange,
              showSizeChanger: false, // set to false to hide pageSizeOptions
            }} scroll={{ x: 'max-content' }}
          />
        </Col>
      </Row>

    </>
  );
};
```

**(2)edited to show Reproducible Code Online______________below**

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/wonderful-wave-2e6bof?file=%2Fpages%2Foperate.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A17%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A97%2C%22startColumn%22%3A17%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A97%7D%5D

**(3)edited title______________Answered Question**

JS constant question (using React,NextJS, Ant Design) :: const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(defaultPageSize); setPageSize is not working

to

children's onChange was not Updating the Parent Element :: Ant Design `Select` and `Table` inside `Tab` was not changing according to changed `pageSize`

setPageSize was working fine, I had problems with children and parenting the code.

Answer: in using Tabs, I needed to use Tab with {initialItems}, bringing the children(initialItems) elements to the same level with the parents(Tab).

```
          <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1">
            {initialItems.map(item => (
              <Tabs.TabPane tab={item.label} key={item.key}>
                {item.children}
              </Tabs.TabPane>
            ))}
          </Tabs>
```

instead of children(initialItems) inside children(items) inside parent(Tab)

```
const initialItems = [
    { label: 'Tab1', key: '1', children: InitialSetting() },
    { label: 'Tab2', key: '2', children: NFTInformation() },
  ];
  const [items, setItems] = useState(initialItems);
<Tabs defaultActiveKey="1" type="card" size={'middle'} items={items} />
```

as changes in children(initialItems) were not detected in parent(Tab) element.

Thank you for helping out!

Comment: Where and how are you calling `handlePageSizeChange`? If it's in an event listener, please share how you're adding that event listener (eg, if it's being added in a `useEffect()`)

Comment: @NickParsons

              <Select
                    size="middle"
                    value={pageSize}
                    options={itemPageProps}
                    defaultValue={defaultPageSize}
                    onChange={handlePageSizeChange}
                    className="w-[150px]"
                  />

Comment: Is the `Select` component your own component or something provided by a library?

Comment: It's imported using import { Typography, Row, Col, Select, Input, message, Tabs, Table, Button, Space, Form, Modal, DatePicker, InputNumber } from 'antd';

Comment: Have you seen this: [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253) it seems like you might be thinking that calling `setPageSize(newPageSize);` will change `pageSize` immediately, making the new value of `pageSize` available on the next line immediately after calling `setPageSize(newPageSize);`, but that isn't the case. The new value of `pageSize` that you set will only be available when your component rerenders.

Comment: Can you create an online reproducible minimal example with which we could play around?

Comment: Can't you do `console.log("page + new page: " + newPageSize + " + " + newPageSize);`, the value you're expecting `pageSize` to be is the value of `newPageSize` right?, so using `newPageSize` directly would do that

Comment: I tried the following: 
[(1) no change] `const [pageSize = defaultPageSize, setPageSize] = useState<number>(); `
[(2) error invalid hook call] const handlePageSizeChange = (newPageSize: number) => `{useEffect(() => {setPageSize(newPageSize);}, [pageSize]); };`
[(3) no change] `<Select key={pageSize} onChange={(newPage)=>{handlePageSizeChange; setPageSize(newPage)}} />`
[(4) axios network error] `<Select  onChange={async (newValue:number) => { setPageSize(newValue); const response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/operate/members/${newValue}`); `setPageSize(response.data); }}/> }

Comment: I want to log inside handlePageSizeChange using `console.log("page + new page: " + pageSize + " + " + newPageSize);` @NickParsons

Comment: Why do you need to use `pageSize` at all though, doesn't `newPageSize` hold the value you need?

Comment: because the global? pageSize is used in Select and Table. @NickParsons

Comment: @jsy4 yeah, which is fine, because when you call `setPageSize(newPageSize);` your component will rerender, setting the value of `pageSize` to `10` (which is what `Select` and `Table` will get). That rerender doesn't happen immediately though, and so before that occurs, the value of `pageSize` will remain as `5`. If you need to access the value you set it to before the component rerenders within your callback, then use `newPageSize`. Stuff outside the callback will reexecute with the new value of `10` for `pageSize` once your component rerenders.

Comment: @NickParsons I think in the code `Select` and `Table` is not getting the updated pageSize. (maybe bc it's a child component inside `Tab`?)

Comment: I understand rerender doesn't happen immediately now. I might have to rerender `Select ` and `Table ` also in the *Operate* page in order to get updated pageSize as it renders once at start and does not update according to pageSize.

Comment: this "Stuff outside the callback will reexecute with the new value of 10 for pageSize once your component rerenders." gave me the clue, as I didn't see anything reexecuting. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setPageSize` enqueues changes to the component state. It tells React that this component and its children need to re-render with the new state. And re-render will begin some later time, after the execution of `handlePageSizeChange` function. Problem is you are reading the old value `console.log("page + new page: " + pageSize + " + " + newPageSize);` of the `pageSize` state in this line. Because the component is not re-rendered yet with the updated value.

I am not sure whats the use case here for you to get the same result for both `pageSize`, and `newPageSize`, whereas you already have the updated value in `newPageSize` argument.